# BigQuery convert STRING to TIMESTAMP for a string that has timezone offset

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with a STRING column we'll call `col1` that has values that look like this: `2021-12-04 12:53:38:203-06:00`. I am trying to convert these strings into TIMESTAMPS with the same timezone, can be UTC or otherwise, but I am having some difficulties because the timezone offset (the -06:00 part of the string) can vary between a few different timezones.

If I just use `TIMESTAMP(col1)`, I get an error `Invalid timestamp: '2021-12-04 12:53:38:203-06:00'`

I have also tried using `PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%E*S%Z', col1)` with a few different formats for parsing, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the fraction of seconds is separated by a colon (:) instead of a period/ dot (.). Based on BigQuery's [valid timestamps](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#data_types), it should be in this format `2021-12-04 12:53:38.203-06:00`. You may need to revisit your dataset and have it adjusted for BigQuery to recognize the [timestamp type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#timestamp_type) then you can perform any [datetime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#function_list) and [timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#function_list) functions as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below to address wrong format

```
PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%F %H:%M:%E3S%Z', FORMAT('%s.%s', SUBSTR(col1, 1, 19), SUBSTR(col1, 21, 8)))
```

if applied to sample string in your question - results is

[image]